# Windows 10 - Bitlocker - Not prompting for password on startup

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

Is it possible to use Bitlocker on Windows 10, but not being prompted every system boot for Bitlocker password (except for using the USB)?

My computer (Lenovo X1 Carbon) has TPM, but I believe it broke - as since a month it's not discovered and also disappeared from BIOS (strange). But I'm sure I have a TPM - since 2 years I didn't need to put any password on boot at that computer, nor use USB stick.

Comment: It does indeed sound like the reason you are being prompted for the password is because your TPM is no longer functional.  Sadly the only method you can use is decrypt the HDD use the recovery media (which contains the recovyer key) you created 2 years ago to do exactly that.  You will be unable to use another machine, because the use of the TPM module, to decrypt the HDD.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't have the old partition and old system anymore. I clean-installed the Win 10 and enabled bitlocker, but the one based on password not TPM. Now I'm wondering if I can omit inserting the password every time PC boots up...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either a password or USB if you don't have a (functional) TPM, otherwise their would be no security.